# Stay in Germany after masters degree

Tags: germany, visa

I am going to obtain masters degree in mathematics in Berlin. The market in this field is very competitive.

1. How I stay in Germany after graduation? (I heard that 3 years, is it true?)
2. Can I work in different area?
   (I mean not as a mathematician)
   I can work as programmer in IT or, if I will not be lucky, as unskilled worker, like courier, carrier, porter, waiter, stuart,...).

If I find such unskilled job during or after graduation, can I stay in Germany?

Comment: This belongs in Expatriates Stack Exchange. Summarized, with a German degree you should be able to get a six months jobseeker visa after graduation (start preparing the application before you graduate). If you get a job offer in a *well paid* job you can stay. So IT looks good, unskilled work rather less so.

Comment: See [Arbeitsplatzsuche nach erfolgreichem Abschluss des Studiums, Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/aufenthalt/studium/#Suche): **Then the residence permit will be extended for a maximum of 18 months so that you can find a job that is appropriate to your degree.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the comment that this belongs into [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions), but since there is a (heavily downvoted) answer in place I thought I'd add this as an answer, too.

- As a graduate from a German university, you can get a [Aufenthaltserlaubnis zur Arbeitsplatzsuche für Fachkräfte](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324661/) (roughly translated jobseeker's visa for professionals).
- Germany gives work visa ([Blue Card EU](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaue_Karte_EU#Gesetzliche_Voraussetzungen)) to academics with basic language skills and a well paid job offer. How much you have to earn depends on the sector, for an IT job it is about €43k per year. Even an entry-level programmer *can* make that much.

It is important that you start the paperwork before you graduate. The student's organization in your university (ASTA) may be able to help.

Comment: I think it is not called "job seeker visa" since the last requires 5or6 years of experience.  I think it is called "extended residence permit" or sth like that ( https://www.topuniversities.com/student-info/careers-advice/how-work-germany-during-or-after-your-studies )

Comment: @ged, I don't know if there is an "official" translation but what your link writes is not the literal translation of the German Aufenthaltstitel.

Comment: @ged it may not be called that, but the purpose of the extension is to **find a job that is appropriate to your degree**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Who or what decides what is appropriate?

Comment: @ged Sorry, but there are certain things you will just have to figure out for yourself. (Hint1: the authority where the quote, in my comment in the main question, comes from and also issues **residence permits** ; Hint2: it's **not** the local plumber's association **nor** the Girls Scouts of America)

Comment: @ged, you should really ask a new question on Expatriates stack exchange. But a key factor will be that the job is highly paid, the authorities will then assume it is also highly qualified. How much salary there has to be depends on the sector of industry; IT specialists are especially encouraged so they have to show less salary than some other fields.